# Adding an Index to MS word document that is indifferent to capitalization

Tags: microsoft-word, search-indexing

I am making an index in Word.

I noticed that the "Mark Index Entry" box is case-sensitive. Such that it will make two different index entries for "Politics" and "politics." Is there a way to turn off case sensitivity, such as all entries for "Politics" and "politics" can fall under one word?

Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no way built into Word. Fix the entries in the document so they are uniform as to capitalization. You could perhaps use a macro to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a by design feature and cannot be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is by design and cannot be changed to be case-insensitive.

I suggest changing all your instances of lowercase with uppercase characters or vice versa. You should be able to achieve this with the Find and Replace feature:

1. Press **Ctrl + H** to show the Find and Replace dialog.
2. Press the **More** button.
3. Ensure **Match case** is checked.
4. Enter the word to be changed in the **Find what** field, and the same word in either uppercase/lowercase form in the **Replace with** field. (ie. find "Apple" and replace with "apple").

You may also be able to achieve this with a macro.

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-make-my-index-not-case-sensitive/eb3b55a5-f0f1-4a29-bb6f-eca334f65801